# Unable to register Android App with Google Firebase Messaging service: "Not allowed to start service Intent"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to request for (and receive a token from firebase messaging service), but haven't been able to do so.

Firstly, I get the following error showing up in logcat as soon as the application starts (even before something shows up on the emulator or device screen)

```
09-21 18:11:33.183 17858-17858/? D/FirebaseInstanceId: Missing wake lock permission, service start may be delayed
09-21 18:11:33.233 17858-18021/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Unable to get master token
                                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1728)
                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1705)
                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:516)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.b(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.c(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.b(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.f(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.b(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


                                                       [ 09-21 18:11:33.303 18029:18029 W/         ]
                                                       [ColorAdjust] Set temp_prefer temp_ce!
09-21 18:11:37.693 17858-17912/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
09-21 18:13:56.973 19009-19261/? E/MarketConnection: Connection Exception for resolver.gslb.mi-idc.com :java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to resolver.gslb.mi-idc.com/54.255.183.200 (port 80) after 10000ms
09-21 18:13:56.973 19009-19261/? E/MarketConnection: Connection failed : NETWORK_ERROR
09-21 18:14:07.113 19009-19261/? E/MarketConnection: Connection Exception for resolver.gslb.mi-idc.com :java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to resolver.gslb.mi-idc.com/54.255.183.200 (port 80) after 10000ms
09-21 18:14:07.113 19009-19261/? E/MarketConnection: Connection failed : NETWORK_ERROR
```

Here's my **AndroidMainfest.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demoapp.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.demoapp.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.demoapp.myapp.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Google Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>

        <!-- Firebase Message Listening Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessageService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- Firebase Token Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseTokenService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private ListView drawerListView;

    Thread tokenService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //Subscribe to be notified
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    }
```

**FirebaseTokenService.java**

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class FirebaseTokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        registerToken(token);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token", token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url('192.168.1.2/myapp/register.php')
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch(Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;


public class FirebaseMessageService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.org_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
}
```

I have also updated the necessary entries in the build.gradle files

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

//Firebase entry
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and also updates the app level build.gradle file

```
.
.
.
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // (v4.5)
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I put in application in DEBUG, but never is there a call to the FirebaseTokenService even though the MainActivity.java code gets executed completely!

What am I doing wrong/missing? Please help!

Comment: did you fix it??